# How can I shorten a [ qw( ... ) ] construct in Perl?

Tags: arrays, list, perl, anonymous-types

Perl's quote-like operator `qw()` creates a [word list](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) from barewords, while [square brackets](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Square-Brackets) `[]` can be used to create references to anonymous arrays. Now, I was wondering if Perl provides a way to somehow abbreviate this:

```
my $aref = [qw( a b c )];
```

using something like a **non-existent** `qa()` operator:

```
my $aref = qa( a b c );
```

I've been using `qw()` and `[]` together quite a lot recently, and all I want is to reduce cluttering.

Note: This is not what I'm looking for:

```
my @a = \( qw( a b c ) );
```

Comment: Read more at `perldoc perlref`: \qw(a b c) is (\'a', \'b', \'c'). AFAIK there is no shorter solution.

Comment: You mean: `my @a = qw( a b c); my $arrayref= \@a`?

Comment: This is already quite verbose. Why do you need it shorter? Lists are not arrays in Perl. `qw()` gives you a _list_, that has nothing to do with an array as such (apart from that arrays are lists, but not wise versa).

Comment: Can't be shortened in vanilla Perl, that is, without creating a parser plugin for a custom `qa` quote operator.

Comment: Why not to write `my $aref = [ a b c ];` instead?

Comment: @PolarBear That will not work. Did you try it?

Comment: Please see following [code example](https://rextester.com/YBI65332);

Comment: @PolarBear in that code example, you use `[ 'apple', 'pear', 'pineapple'];`, which brings back the quotes and the commas. That's opposite of what the poster wants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not core Perl, but check out [Syntax::Feature::Qwa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Feature::Qwa)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no shorter way with core Perl to express:

```
my $aref = [qw( a b c )];
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion someone made that makes this slightly more readable is to say
[qw[ a b c ]];